# Add group restriction to context menu Odoo

Tags: javascript, xml, odoo-12

I have been given this function in odoo12:

```js
_loadContextMenuFile: function($jstree, node, menu) {
     var self = this;
     menu.download = {
   separator_before: false,
   separator_after: false,
   icon: "fa fa-download",
   label: _t("Download"),
   action: function(data) {
    framework.blockUI();
    session.get_file({
        'url': '/web/content',
        'data': {
            'id': node.data.odoo_id,
            'download': true,
            'field': 'content',
            'model': 'muk_dms.file',
            'filename_field': 'name',
            'filename': node.data.filename
        },
        'complete': framework.unblockUI,
        'error': crash_manager.rpc_error.bind(crash_manager)
    });
   }
     };
     return menu;
```

and it appears when the user right-clicks on a node in the tree, I have been asked is it possible to make this option only available in dev mode. If this was xml i would just add: groups="base.group_no_one". However I have no experience of javascript, is their request possible? Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if you are in dev mode you can use `web.config` module.

```
var config = require('web.config');

if (config.debug) {
    // make the option available
}
```

Comment: I am glad to help and feel free to accept my answer.